# Nokogiri: Searching node with ":"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have a simple XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns:msg="..." xmlns:ld="...">
  <msg:testResultBatch providerId="12345" testName="Hello Labs">
    .
    .
    .
  </msg:testResultBatch>
</response>
```

When I pass it to `Nokogiri.XML` like:

```
req = Nokogiri.XML('
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <response xmlns:msg="..." xmlns:ld="...">
      <msg:testResultBatch providerId="12345" testName="Hello Labs">
        .
        .
        .
      </msg:testResultBatch>
    </response>
')
```

I'm unable to search nodes with ":". So,

```
req.search("response") # works
```

but,

```
req.search("msg:testResultBatch") # doesn't works
```

and gives me `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using xpath and `'//msg:testResultBatch'` you can get the `msg:testResultBatch`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

req = Nokogiri.XML('
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns:msg="..." xmlns:ld="...">
  <msg:testResultBatch providerId="12345" testName="Hello Labs">
  </msg:testResultBatch>
</response>
')
p req.xpath('//msg:testResultBatch').first.name # "testResultBatch"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But, may I know why search didn't pick it up?

Comment: Mmh, really it does, but using [xpath or css](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/xml/searchable.rb#L18), it seems that `msg:testResultBatch` doesn't look like none of them. So both would work, xpath and search.

Comment: Well `search` doesn't work for me :-(. Thanks anyways (Y)

Comment: Glad to help ;)